# Android mp4 videos in raw do not work after widevine signing

Tags: android, mp4

My problem is that before the signing with widevine the video is displayed as it should.

The video is located in resources/raw

Errors I get are :

```
I/MediaPlayer(23023): path is null
D/MediaPlayer(23023): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

Does anyone have a idea of the root of this error or even a workaround ?

I tried to put the videos in assets but there was no difference

Thanks in advance and I hope there is someone out there that can help me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming widewine is a drm, you need to decrypt before you can play. Either widewine will give you a player or a decrypting library which you must use to decrypt the content before you can play it.

Comment: The case is, that the video is playable by every normal player if I export it from the .apk, so it seems to me that it is not encrypted.